# adding a 3rd party test framework for ASP.NET MVC3 and Razor view engine

Tags: asp.net, testing, asp.net-mvc-3, nunit, razor

Would like to add a third party test framework (such as NUnit or MbUnit) to the drop-down list of test projects for the ASP.NET MVC3 type project in Visual Studio 2010.

[image: adding 3rd party test frameworks]

This had worked before for ASP.NET MVC2 and prior, but the msdn instructions are not accurate and does not work.  Creating the registry keys in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER seem to delete the keys every time the VS-2010 starts, the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE does not follow the same tree structure.

Does anyone know how to add a third party framework under ASP.NET MVC3?

[image: From the RegEx - adding keys manually]

[This resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381614.aspx) and [this rant](http://www.geekbeing.com/2010/07/21/asp-mvc-2-nunit-based-unit-test-project-template/) do not work for MVC3

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really good blog post explaining how to add [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) as another 3rd party test framework to the ASP.NET MVC 3 (up to RTM) project's dropdown list:

- [ASP.NET MVC 3 with NUnit Testproject](http://blog.kimpenhaus.de/2010/12/16/asp-net-mvc-3-with-nunit-testproject-updated-template/)

This post also provides a full package to download with all the required files (intstall batch, registry keys and the Visual Studio template) to easily set it up by yourself.

Comment: this blog post is similar to the one I have noted in the resources, however it still does not work.  First of all, the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE construct does not carry the same tree signature, the proposed tree structure only shows within HKEY_CURRENT_USER hierarchy.  The MVC3 folder shown above is also placed in 10.0_Config key directory.  Perhaps I am missing something obvious, but not sure.  I don't want to spend too much time on this, because it really did work for MVC2 and prior.

Comment: @baskint: Based on the comments on the blog post I believed it should work and would help you. Also ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM is mentioned explicitly. However, I tried the `install.bat` by myself and have to admit that I do not get the NUnit option in Visual Studio either. I'm running Windows 7 x64 and Visual Studio 2010 Premium.

Comment: Agreed. I tried on one Windows 7 x64 & VS-2010 Ultimate, and one Windows Server 2008 R2 & VS-2010 professional.  The registry keys I placed in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER are purged every time the VS-2010 starts and NUnit option (template) is not displayed. Thanks for confirming that.

Comment: The asp.net MVC 3 with NUnit Testproject page the link points to is currently dead

Answer (score 1):

sad to hear it doesn't work for you. Regarding the problems about having the HKEY_CURRENT_USER and loosing the pasted key each time Visual Studio starts I would like you to read about it here: [All your RegKeys Are Belong To Us](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronmar/archive/2009/11/06/all-your-regkeys-are-belong-to-us.aspx) At the end it says:

> If you edit a key in 10.0_Config, Visual Studio will (quite possibly) delete it on startup.

Guess that's what you see while editing and starting. Next thing is such a suggestion - not sure about that - but are you having UAC enabled and run Visual Studio in RANU (= run as normal user) mode? This link: [Developing Packages as a Normal User (or How I Learned to Love UAC)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronmar/archive/2007/06/06/developing-packages-as-a-normal-user-i-e.aspx) shows up, that Visual Studio introduced a certain switch which affetcs it to look into different registry places:

> When running with the /RANU switch (along with /rootsuffix Exp in this case), Visual Studio will instead look in the following locations:
>
> Package Registration : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0Exp\Configuration
> User Settings: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0Exp\UserSettings

Last post I like to give you with this describes the startup (registry and pkgdef merge) routine of Visual Studio: blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronmar/archive/2009/06/05/pkgdef-and-the-experimental-instance-in-vs-2010.aspx [sorry - can only post 2 links]

If you could provide me with some more informations about Setup (UAC? anything else to be mentioned) I will try to provide a package update which will fix this. The curious thing is that I am running VS2010 Ultimate on Win 7 64bit - and the installer works ok. Only thing - I am not running in UAC ;-)

Marcus.

Comment: In the meantime I published an extension (installable via ExtensionManager or downloadable via [VisualStudio-Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7f3bdc82-f418-41aa-ad15-f1d6f89df47a)). That package depends on the PackageDefinition file as mentioned in the links above. Maybe you can try this out if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're trying to do, its a little complicated for what you get out of it though. If you zip up a project template based on whatever testing framework you use and drop it in the correct folder, you can simply add your templated project to your initial Mvc 3 solution after its created.  It seriously might take an extra 5 secs, plus you can use it for any other type of solution you might want tests for.

Comment: my goal is to show that the drop down shows other test templates (frameworks, if you will).  Again I had this working as noted versions prior to MVC2, but not MVC3 it seems like.  Not sure what broke?